# How to get element using array index

Tags: bash, shell

I have an array named `test` which has these contents:

```
a b c d e f.
```

I got these array from string which has :

```
a/b/c/d/e/f
```

I split the above string to an array using this:

```
test=$(echo $dUrl | tr "/" "\n")
```

Now I wish to get the `test`'s first element using `${test[1]}`, but its giving me nothing.

Where I'm making the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` is not an array but a multiline string in your script, one way to get an element (eg the second) would be:

```
echo "$test" | sed -n '2p'
```

If you want to build a real array, you can use that syntax:

```
typeset -a test=( $(echo $dUrl|tr "/" " ") )
```

Then, `${test[2]}` whill show you the second element as you expect.

Answer (score 3):

A **Bash only** solution would be to use [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and [IFS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS) for that.

```
var="a/b/c/d/e/f"
IFS=/; # redefine word-splitting on slash character
arr=( $var ) # use word-splitting :)
```

#### A Better Alternative

Using the [`read built-in`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read) is more secure:

```
var="a/b/c/d/e"
IFS=/ read -rd '' -a arr <<<"$var"
```

- [`-r`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read#read_without_-r): disables interpretion of backslash escapes and line-continuation in the read data ;
- `-a <ARRAY>`: store in `<ARRAY>`, read the data word-wise into the specified array  instead of normal variables ;
- `-d <DELIM>`: recognize `<DELIM>` as data-end, rather than `<newline>`.

#### Test

```
echo "${arr[0]}" # → a
echo "${arr[1]}" # → b
echo "${arr[2]}" # → c
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert a string to array before you index it.

Like

```
arr=($test)
echo ${arr[2]}
```

As per your question

```
$ dUrl="a/b/c/d/e/f"
$ test=$(echo $dUrl | tr "/" "\n")
$ echo $test
a b c d e f
$ a=($test)
$ echo ${a[1]}
b
```